# Type inference for arrays of tuple pairs

Tags: typescript

How can I type my `create` function so that it can safely infer individual types for each pair it receives?

```
type Component<T=any> = { id: string, _type?: T };

type Pair<T=any> = [Component<T>, T];

function create<T extends Pair[]>(...pairs: T) {
  // ...
}

type Vector = [number, number];
type Status = "active" | "idle";

let Position: Component<Vector> = { id: "position" };
let Status: Component<Status> = { id: "status" };

let entity = create(
  [Position, [0, 0]],
  [Status, false], // should fail as it expects `Status` and got `boolean`
);
```

[Playground version](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gWzHAdhFwA8AVAvAQxRAD4pcoBvKASwBMAuKAZ2ACdqUBzKAXwG4AUKEhQACvmqscBIqXIBteElTos2YgBoo2ALqCBAMwCuKAMbBqqKKdYR8wCAAoAdK7ATWTRuMnydASkoBKCgAelCoV2cBHgEhcGgANQhzOFYyKHkUIwQAIwhWLWy8gr14kQBlYHsjJgyAInxzagA3CHqoAB8oeroAG3b9AeAxOCZqC1RGJWQ0DExk1NY5ShoGHuRxyZQO-gFhqCqar1hEWdVMI+Balao6RnqWY92hiBHVCZAMmzsHR2DMqIxhNLCgtPIAAxaCE6HQaAHyK61LQGfB9JgQOFhCJMAAWcCMfVoUFR1D6UHwdQmUAgAA9IOY6gADJFMJkUlDEzhwEZM3JwOADQhMgT+PhAA)

I can achieve the desired behaviour by passing the type parameter explicitly.

```
let entity = create<[
  Pair<Vector>,
  Pair<Status>,
]>(
  [Position, [0, 0]],
  [Status, false], // should fail as it expects `Status` and got `boolean`
);
```

My hunch here is that the compiler won't attempt to infer the nested `Pair` types from their elements, once it has already inferred the `pairs` parameter to be of type `Pair[]`.

Comment: you just defined Pair with Pait<T = any> so Pair is of type [Component<any>, any]...

Comment: I know. That's why I'm trying to figure out how to infer that type instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting such a correlation inside the item of an array is not very straight forward in TS. One of the solutions, as outlined in another answer is to have a dedicated function a pair, and invoke that on each item. While this solution works it is not ideal as it forces user to remember to opt into this check.

Another solution is to use a custom way of performing the check. This was relies on the following:

If a parameter is an intersection that contains a type parameter and a second type relying on that type parameter (ex: `T & SomeMappedType<T>`) typescript will infer the type parameter `T` will and use the inferred type in `SomeMappedType<T>` and check the parameter against `SomeMappedType<T>`. Basically we capture the actual type of the parameter in `T`, but perform the check against a separate type that relies on `T`.

What this means for this example is that we will use a type parameter to capture the actual type of the array as a tuple (in your example: `[[Component<Vector>, number[]], [Component<Status>, boolean]]`) and then use this type to build the type which we actually want to check against (in this example it should be `[Pair<Vector>, Pair<Status>]`). We will use a simple mapped type to do this.

```
type Component<T> = { id: string, usage?: T };
type Pair<T> = [Component<T>, T];
type PairCheck<T extends Pair<any>[]> = {
  [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends [Component<infer U>, any] ? Pair<U>: never
}
function create<T extends Pair<any>[]>(...pairs: T & PairCheck<T>) {
  // ...
}

type Vector = [number, number];
type Status = "active" | "idle";

let Position: Component<Vector> = { id: "position" };
let Status: Component<Status> = { id: "status" };

let entity = create(
  [Position, [0, 0]],
  [Status, true],
);
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gWzHAdhFwA8AVAfFAXigG8oBLAEwC4oBnYAJzJQHMAaKAV1oEMWIA-DWxQAvgG4AUKEhQACjzIMc+IgG14SVOix4O2ALpSZ0BUpgALCAGMA1jigQAHsHQVa8xcp4oQuNQaqJJJQUGpy5ChQthAgcABmUIbC4QaOLm4eGojIaBiYzPEQDFAAqrgcPiBpAp5KmOU0aABuxZKikvGcKNbAZKhQ1gwQPK4Ozq4o7nXevv6BABQAdCtgXrTCUABkM5Y29ngAlMGhAPSnUCtL7ZLS4NAAajbAcCXqKJwIAEbFHB-fxSMd1kAGVgKNuIQoAAiHi9MitaFQAA+MMoABsINCpJJMcB5HBaGQ+qgaJpcjpME9eq8gqRKDRocgiSSUEiJLiIPiwRCNrActp8jzgNw6eRqDD6Lz2Ti8Y4MMSQFChiNXAsQmE5ITif0UBw1AAGDgGgwGNgatTC7gcRicCBmySHcRAA)

**Note**: `Component` MUST use `T` in order for any of this to work. Read [FAQ](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#generics) about unused type parameters.

The error you get is

```
Argument of type '[[Component<Vector>, [number, number]], [Component<Status>, boolean]]' is not assignable to parameter of type '[[Component<Vector>, number[]], [Component<Status>, boolean]] & [Pair<Vector>, Pair<Status>]'.
  Type '[[Component<Vector>, [number, number]], [Component<Status>, boolean]]' is not assignable to type '[Pair<Vector>, Pair<Status>]'.
    Type '[Component<Status>, boolean]' is not assignable to type 'Pair<Status>'.
      Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'Status'
```

Which is a mouth-full, and the error span is regrettably on the first element not the offending one (which might actually be a compiler bug), but it does make clear what is wrong IMO.

Answer (score 1):

All items of your [rest parameter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#rest-parameters) `...pairs` in `create` are packed to one common type extending `Pair[]` (with `T` resolved to `any` in the default case). The compiler interprets the given arguments as an array and the items' type in an array is the same, so there is no chance here to do a type check for the individual items without type annotations.

One alternative is the sample you provided by manually typing the generic type parameter for `create` or separate the function arguments from the function invocation:

```
const t: [Pair<Vector>, Pair<Status>] = [[Position, [0, 0]], [Status, false]]; // error (OK)
let entity = create(...t);
```

This solution is viable, when there is a fixed amount of `Pair` items to be passed in `create` or when the compound type of all `Pair` items is known. When that's not possible and/or the array is created in a more dynamic way, you could use some helper function `asPair`, whose single purpose is to enforce the strong typing of `Pair` like this:

```
function asPair<T>(t: Pair<T>) {
  return t;
}

let entity = create(
  asPair([Position, [0, 0]]),
  asPair([Status, false]) // error: Type 'false' is not assignable to type 'Status'. (OK)
);
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gWzHAdhFwA8AVKBeKAQxRAD58oBvKASwBMAuKAZ2ACcaUBzKAXwG4AUKEhQACoRpscFYmQoBteElTos2UgBoo2ALpDBAMwCuKAMbAaqKGbYRCwCAAoAdG7CS2zJhKkLdAJRUglBQAPRhUG4ugryCwuDQAGoQFnBsiijGCABGEGzaWbn5+gmiAMrADsbMFABEhBY0AG4QdVAAPlB19AA2bQb9wOJwzDSWqEzKyGgYmClpbOQE1PRMdchjEyjtAoJDUJXV3rCIM2qYR8A1y1S0jN2sx7sGJubbRMy+0hpOwD6eHCkIKUEJQOzXNgoKDAIRxfYQYZqcYgCi2eyOJxgwhfTxOBRiUbjKwobQKAAM2nJukCmmxuKk+KuNW0hkIvWYEECggC-CAA)